# Struts1 Preety url

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1, seo

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <!--<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>-->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am doing like this to obtain my url seo friendly.
Now i am facing a problem is that to my one of my controller i am passing parameter : test1.in as

http://www.myweb.com/manage/test1.in

So in manage action servlet i get the parameter as test1 but not test1.in, can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Got solution to this problem using request object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friends, finally i got solution to this problem is :
using request object

```
String requestUrlTemp = new String(request.getRequestURL());
String requestUrl = "";   
requestUrl= URLDecoder.decode(requestUrlTemp, "UTF-8" );
```